# Stop hibernate from firing update query on @ManyToOne entities

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities ProductCartItem and Product. A product in my scenario is more of a master record that is never gonna change. Below is the mapping.

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "PRODUCT")
public class ProductCartItem extends CartItem {

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Product product;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, mappedBy = "parentProductCartItem",orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonManagedReference
Set<AccessoryCartItem> associatedAccessories = new HashSet<>();

@Column(name="property")
@Type(type = "ProductItemPropertyUserType")
private ProductItemProperty productItemProperty;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="project_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
private Project project;

public Product getProduct() {
    return product;
}

public void setProduct(Product product) {
    this.product = product;
}

public Set<AccessoryCartItem> getAssociatedAccessories() {
    return associatedAccessories;
}

public void setAssociatedAccessories(Set<AccessoryCartItem> associatedAccessories) {
    this.associatedAccessories = associatedAccessories;
}

public void addAccessory(AccessoryCartItem accessoryCartItem) {
    this.getAssociatedAccessories().add(accessoryCartItem);
}

public void removeAccessory(AccessoryCartItem accessoryCartItem) {
    this.getAssociatedAccessories().remove(accessoryCartItem);
}

public ProductItemProperty getProductItemProperty() {
    return productItemProperty;
}

public void setProductItemProperty(ProductItemProperty productItemProperty) {
    this.productItemProperty = productItemProperty;
}

public Project getProject() {
    return project;
}

public void setProject(Project project) {
    this.project = project;
}
}
```

And here is the Product entity.

```
 @Entity
 public class Product extends BaseEntity {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "subtitle")
    private String subtitle;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "type_name")
    private String typeName;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private Float price;

    @Column(name = "image_list")
    @Type(type = "MyImageListUserType")
    private MyImageList imageList;

    @Column(name = "pricing_property")
    @Type(type = "PricingProperty")
    private Map<String,SizePriceDTO> pricingProperty;

    @JoinColumn(name = "product_type")
    @ManyToOne
    private ProductType productType;

    private String orientation;

    private Short groupId;

    @Column(name = "display_order")
    private Short displayOrder;

    @Column(name = "base_quantity")
    private int baseQuantity;

    @Transient
    private List<AccessoryDTO> configuredAccessoryDTOList;

    public Product(){
    }


    public int getBaseQuantity() {
        return baseQuantity;
    }

    public void setBaseQuantity(int baseQuantity) {
        this.baseQuantity = baseQuantity;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getSubtitle() {
        return subtitle;
    }

    public void setSubtitle(String subtitle) {
        this.subtitle = subtitle;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getTypeName() {
        return typeName;
    }


    public void setTypeName(String typeName) {
        this.typeName = typeName;
    }

    public Float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public MyImageList getImageList() {
        return imageList;
    }

    public void setImageList(MyImageList imageList) {
        this.imageList = imageList;
    }

    public ProductType getProductType() {
        return productType;
    }

    public void setProductType(ProductType productType) {
        this.productType = productType;
    }
    public String getOrientation() {
        return orientation;
    }

    public void setOrientation(String orientation) {
        this.orientation = orientation;
    }

    public Short getGroupId() {
        return groupId;
    }


    public void setGroupId(Short groupId) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }


    public Short getDisplayOrder() {
        return displayOrder;
    }


    public void setDisplayOrder(Short displayOrder) {
        this.displayOrder = displayOrder;
    }

public List<AccessoryDTO> getConfiguredAccessoryDTOList() {
    return configuredAccessoryDTOList;
}

public void setConfiguredAccessoryDTOList(List<AccessoryDTO> configuredAccessoryDTOList) {
    this.configuredAccessoryDTOList = configuredAccessoryDTOList;
}

public Map<String, SizePriceDTO> getPricingProperty() {
    return pricingProperty;
}

public void setPricingProperty(Map<String,SizePriceDTO> pricingProperty) {
    this.pricingProperty = pricingProperty;
}
}
```

Now when I create a new ProductCartItem I associate an already existing Product with it. When I save the productcartitem hibernate for some reasons is firing an update query on the product table too. I have already tried setting the relationship as updatable= false but to no avail. Below is the code for the service.

```
private ShoppingCart addProductToCartHelper(ProductCartItemDTO productCartItemDTO) throws ShoppingException{
    ShoppingCart shoppingCart;
    ProductCartItem productCartItem;
    Product product = productService.getProductById(productCartItemDTO.getProductDTO().getId().intValue());
    if (null == product) {
        throw new ShoppingException();
    }
    Customer currentCustomer = CanveraWebUtil.getCurrentCustomer();
    GuestUser guestUser = guestUserService.loadGuestUserByUUID(CanveraWebUtil.getCurrentGuestUserIdentifier());
    shoppingCart = fetchShoppingCartForCustomerOrGuestUser();
    if (null == shoppingCart) {
        if (null != currentCustomer) {
            shoppingCart = new ShoppingCart(currentCustomer);
        } else {
            shoppingCart = new ShoppingCart(guestUser);
        }
        shoppingCart.setShoppingBagStatus(ShoppingBagStatus.DRAFT);
    }
    Long productCartItemDTOId = productCartItemDTO.getId();
    // we will not update the associated accessories as in our case these never comes from our UI.
    if (null == productCartItemDTOId) {
        modifyNumberOfPages(productCartItemDTO,product);
        productCartItem = new ProductCartItem();
        productCartItem.setProductItemProperty(productCartItemDTO.getProductItemProperty());
        productCartItem.setQuantity(productCartItemDTO.getQuantity());
        productCartItem.setProduct(product);
        productCartItem.setPrice(productCartItemDTO.getPrice());
        productCartItem.setGiftWrap(shoppingCart.getIsGiftWrap());
        //associating project
        productCartItem.setProject(productCartItemDTO.getProject());

        shoppingCart.addCartItem(productCartItem);
        productCartItem.setShoppingCart(shoppingCart);
    } else {
        for (CartItem cartItem : shoppingCart.getCartItems()) {
            if (null != cartItem.getId() && cartItem.getId().equals(productCartItemDTOId)) {
                productCartItem  = (ProductCartItem) cartItem;
                productCartItem.setProductItemProperty(productCartItemDTO.getProductItemProperty());
                productCartItem.setPrice(productCartItemDTO.getPrice());
                productCartItem.setQuantity(productCartItemDTO.getQuantity());
            }
        }
    }
    shoppingCart = shoppingCartRepository.save(shoppingCart);
    return shoppingCart;
}
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction ? At any point of time I do not alter any property of the product object.

Comment: No help till now. I thought many would have encountered this problem before.

Comment: what is the query that you state "firing an update query on the product table too" is it save new product?

Comment: @Angga No it is firing an update query on the product table.

Comment: what is the query? exact same value with old value you mean?

Comment: @Angga In my case a product can be seen as a master table using which you can add items (cart-items) to the shopping cart. So any cartitem refers to a product. Now when any cartitem is updated/inserted an update query is fired on the product table. But this is not required. The exact same value with old values. Yes

Comment: I am still stuck with it. I tried it within a new project . In case of a manytoone mapping it is not usual for hibernate to compulsory update the one side of the relationship whenever the many side of the relationship is updated or inserted. Can't say why it is happening in my case.

Comment: only when the product is modified it should be updated. in your code it seems you are not modifying it, the only suspicious point is the call of `modifyNumberOfPages(productCartItemDTO,product);`

Comment: @KevinPeters Thanks for taking the time out . I really appreciate the effort. I have solved the issue myself. Actually in the Product entity if you see MyImageList is a custom user type of hibernate that I have implemerented. So I had a problem over there . I had to implement the equals method correctly otherwise Hibernate thinks that it is a dirty objecct and that's why the update was happening.

Comment: Awesome :) thanks for the reply :)